# Specific Like, Twitter and Pinterest buttons for each image in the gallery?

Tags: facebook, image, wordpress, facebook-like, gallery

The site I am working on is on WordPress.
I am trying to create a picture gallery now but I would like that each image will have its own URL and social buttons.
It means that you will be able to see an image, like it, see it posted on your wall with the correct thumbnail and redirect to the correct page in the gallery again. 
I tried with the simple WordPress gallery and with NextGEN gallery, until now. Unfortunately I didn't get a good result yet.

Here is what I could do with NextGEN until now:

[Gallery Main Page](http://www.101greatgoals.com/gallery/)

[Gallery Image Page](http://www.101greatgoals.com/gallery/gimages/image/gabriel_batistuta_0/)

Problems I have there:

1. When I like an image, the thumb that appears in Facebook is wrong.
2. Same about the redirection URL from Facebook that takes me to the main gallery instead of the specific image that I liked.
3. Same with Twitter.

This is the code I am using on the image pages:
http://jsbin.com/ujahex/watch

Many thanks!

Comment: You have an error in your OG code that you'll need to address, it is likely this is causing your problems with Facebook at least:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.101greatgoals.com%2Fgallery%2Fgimages%2Fimage%2Fgabriel_batistuta_0%2F

Comment: Yes I see that now and you're right, but still the page can be shared and a totally different URL and image are being shared on Facebook. I am looking into what I can do to get the correct image and redirection URL. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MatthewJohnston Do you recommend doing something specific?